# Expanding variadic types into another

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, sfinae, c++17

I'm trying to expand a pack of variadic types to another type by doing something like this.

I have a simple trait that gets enabled when `TFunction` returns `TReturn`.

```
template<typename TReturn, typename TFunction>
using ReturnsType = enable_if_t<is_same<decltype(declval<TFunction>()()), 
                                TReturn>::value>;
```

it works perfectly in all main compilers (VC++, GCC, CLANG).

Now i want to create another one with this notation:

```
template<typename TReturn, typename... TFunctions>
using AllReturnsType = ???
```

so it gets enabled only if all the passed functions (`TFunctions...`) do return `TReturn`.

So I tried this implementation:

```
template<typename TReturn, typename... TFunctions>
using AllReturnsType = void_t<ReturnsType<TReturn, TFunctions>...>;
```

but it fails in VC++ (it's fine in GCC and CLANG)

code playground can be found here: https://godbolt.org/g/d839wp

Is this a bug in MSVC++? how can I make it work in all compilers?

Thanks!

Edit: I'm in contact with MSVC team members and they are taking care of it! It is a confirmed bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a bug in MSVC++?

Yes, I think so.

> how can I make it work in all compilers?

Don't ask me why but seems that, if you pass through an helper `struct` for `enable_if_returns` as follows

```
template <typename T, typename F, 
          bool = std::is_same_v<T, get_return_type<F>>>
struct enIfR
{ };

template <typename T, typename F>
struct enIfR<T, F, true>
{ using type = T; };

template <typename T, typename F>
using enable_if_returns = typename enIfR<T, F>::type;
```

your code compile also in MSVC.

The following is a full compiling (MSVC also) example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Function>
using get_return_type = decltype(std::declval<Function>()());

template <typename T, typename F,
         bool = std::is_same_v<T, get_return_type<F>>>
struct enIfR
 { };

template <typename T, typename F>
struct enIfR<T, F, true>
 { using type = T; };

template <typename T, typename F>
using enable_if_returns = typename enIfR<T, F>::type;

template<typename T, typename Function>
using enable_if_returns0 = typename std::enable_if<
   std::is_same<T, get_return_type<Function>>::value>::type;

template<typename T, typename... Functions>
using enable_if_all_returns = std::void_t<typename enIfR<T, Functions>::type...>;

int main()
{
    constexpr auto fint = []() -> int { return 1; };
    constexpr auto fstring = []() -> std::string { return "asd"; };

    (enable_if_returns<int, decltype(fint)>)0; // ok
    //(enable_if_returns<int, decltype(fstring)>)0; // fail on all (expected)
    //(enIfR<int, decltype(fstring)>::type)0; // fail on all (expected)

    (enable_if_all_returns<int, decltype(fint)>)0; // fail in MSVC (NOT expected, 'get_return_type<unknown-type>' being compiled)
    //(enable_if_all_returns<int, decltype(fint), decltype(string)>)0; // fail in all (expected)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your response. Unfortunately the proxy-struct solution doesn't work in my real code (I simplified it a lot for the POC). I reported the bug to MSVC but... shame on them! this is C++11 stuff!

Comment: @IvanSanz: I agree that it appears to be a bug, but if you uses `std::result_of` then it appears to work (unfortunately std::invoke_result doesn't appear to be supported by MSVC yet): [Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/Vus8pj)

Comment: @AndyG - Interesting. IMHO, you should present this observations (and the demo code) as an answer.

Comment: @IvanSanz - sorry but... have you tried AndyG's solution? If works... IMHO is far better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [max66](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48361985/27678) that it appears to be a MSVC bug. If I had to guess what was happening, I would say it probably comes down to the fact that MSVC still doesn't have full support for expression SFINAE.

It seems [they've been making steady improvements](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/expression-sfinae-improvements-in-vs-2015-update-3/), though, and their implementation of [std::result_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) is advertised to use it.

Coincidentally, what you're trying to achieve with `get_return_type`:

```
template<typename Function>
using get_return_type = decltype(declval<Function>()());
```

Has already been done with `std::result_of` (deprecated), and [`std::invoke_result`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of)

Since the latest MSVC appears to lack support for `std::invoke_result`, it appears that if we modify your code to use `std::result_of` instead, it all compiles just fine:

```
template<class Function>
using get_return_type = typename std::result_of<Function()>::type;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/g/Vus8pj)